# Can not set Google Translate on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

In Firefox i was able to double-click and translate a word by using an add-on. But firefox tried something and can get only English explanation of english words.
I want to see the double-clicked English word's explanation, meaning in my language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Translate is for translating entire pages rather than individual words, but you can configure the language options like detailed here: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173424. It sounds like you were previously using the [gTranslate plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gtranslate/) for Firefox and there's a few similar plugins for Chrome such as [Bubble Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jlhlebbhengjlhmcjebbkambaekglhkf.) or [Translate Selection](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/goanabmlmgfinmjohhepcpffcnkeobjm) that will translate individual words on the page.